# Getting two most recent entries to two given dates with EF 6

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

(Sorry for the vague title, not really sure what to make it.)

This is .NET 4.7, EF 6.1. I have two tables: a set of products and a set of historical prices. I need to write some code that will get the list of all products and their prices as of two provided dates (start and end). This is essentially a report to see how the product prices have changed between the two dates, but I only need the start/end prices, not everything in between.

The only way I've been able to think of is something like the code below. I would run that twice--once for the start date and once for the end date--then I would join those two lists into one list of the model type that I need. I cannot for the life of me figure out how to do this though. **How should I accomplish this?**

Simplified table layout:

```
Product        HistoricalPrice
-------        ---------------
-Id            -Id
-Name          -ProductId
               -ModifiedAt
               -NewPrice
```

Here's the code I attempted to use. `Product` is a reference to the `HistoricalPrice`'s `Product`, it's part of the class and is referenced with the `ProductId` field. I need to get the product name/ID in the final result from this code.

```
var historicalStartPrices = await _context.ProductHistoricalPrices

    // need to include the product itself
    .Include(p => p.Product)

    // only get prices that come before the start date
    .Where(p => p.ModifiedAt <= start)

    // order from most recent -> oldest by modified date
    .OrderByDescending(p => p.ModifiedAt)

    // group prices by the product ID
    .GroupBy(p => p.ProductId)

    // take only the first result for each product ID
    .Select(g => g.First())

    // enumerate the results
    .ToListAsync();
```

That code throws this exception:

> NotSupportedException: The method 'First' can only be used as a final query operation. Consider using the method 'FirstOrDefault' in this instance instead.

If I switch to `FirstOrDefault`, then all `Product`s are null.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to include Products to Product Historical Prices? Isn't this tables are related?
Maybe a simple modification of your code will help to your goal:

```
var historicalStartPrices = await _context.ProductHistoricalPrices;

// only get prices that come between start and end dates
.Where(p => p.ModifiedAt >= start && p.ModifiedAt <= end

// order from most recent -> oldest by modified date
.OrderByDescending(p => p.ModifiedAt)

// take only prices foreach products in ProductHistoricalPrices
.Select(g => g.NewPrice)

// enumerate the results
.ToListAsync();
```

Comment: I just added this to the question, sorry for the confusion. `Product` is a reference to the `HistoricalPrice`'s `Product`, it's part of the class and is referenced with the `ProductId` field. I need to get the product name/ID in the final result from this code.

Answer (score 0):

This may be referenced elsewhere in your code, but to what is `p.Product` referring? I don't see a generic field like that in your table.

Also if you're trying to take the first result for the Id that needs to go next to the field you're querying for.

Assuming the first query isn't necessary, your query could look otherwise the same:

```
.Where(p => p.ModifiedAt <= start)
.OrderByDescending(p => p.ModifiedAt)
.GroupBy(p => p.ProductId.First())
.ToListAsync();
```

If you really need to reference an item from the other table, you could either store that value in a variable, or you could simply retrieve your most recent entry: `query.Where(p => p.ModifiedAt

Comment: I just added this to the question, sorry for the confusion. `Product` is a reference to the `HistoricalPrice`'s `Product`, it's part of the class and is referenced with the `ProductId` field. I need to get the product name/ID in the final result from this code.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to your question (**each product initial and final price within range of time**) is for you to have your Linq query look like the following:

```
var historicalPrices = await _context.ProductHistoricalPrices.Where(x => x.ModifiedAt >= startDate && x.ModifiedAt <= endDate).Select(x => new
    {
     ProductId = x.ProductId,
     ProductName = x.Product.Name,
     Price = x.NewPrice,
     ModificationDate = x.ModifiedAt
    }).GroupBy(x => x.ProductId).Select(x => new
{
  ProductName = x.FirstOrDefault().ProductName,
  InitialPrice = x.OrderBy(x => x.ModificationDate).FirstOrDefault().Price,
  FinalPrice = x.OrderByDescending(x => x.ModificationDate).FirstOrDefault().Price
}).ToListAsync();
```